# JSON decode get the last element, PHP end

Tags: php

I want to get the last element in the JSON decoded array,
Error I am getting

> Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array

`$data` output

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [contact001] => stdClass Object ( [age] => 33 [name] => Robert [tel] => 87778787878787878 ) 
    [contact002] => stdClass Object ( [age] => 33 [name] => Calvin [tel] => 87778787878787878 ) 
)
```

PHP code:

```
$namejson = $firebase->get(DEFAULT_PATH . '/name/');

$data=json_decode($namejson);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo end($key);
}
```

> Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array

Comment: json_decode has two arguments, try TRUE as the second to turn into an array.

Comment: $data=json_decode($namejson,TRUE); @Progrock still the same error warning

Comment: You cannot call `end()` on the **key** of the array. You probably want `end($data)` without the `foreach`, or `end($value)` within the `foreach`.

Comment: If you include the data (JSON), and the output you desire it would help.

Comment: `$key` is a string. It will never be an array.

Comment: @Progrock I want to increment the key i.e contact001 , so I wanted to get the last key key element which will help me to store the new record in the new key ,if you have a better solution let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you decode your `$namejson` json string to array, you can use `array_keys` to get **array of keys**, that are present in your array. Next, you need the last key from this array, use `array_pop` for this. And because the last key is a string, you can use simple `++` operator to increment the value:

```
$data = json_decode($namejson, true);
$keys = array_keys($data);
$last_key = array_pop($keys);
echo 'Last key: ' . $last_key;
$last_key++;
$next_key = $last_key;
echo 'Next key: ' . $next_key;
```

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know you could use `++` on a string to increment the number. Just one minor thing: JSON doesn't need to be sorted, so I'd explicitly sort `$keys` to make sure the last key actually has the highest number.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks a lot it helped me to get my query solution

Comment: Not only numbers. Strings like `aaaa` can be incremented too. New value will be `aaab`. But do it with caution.

Comment: @u_mulder to get the "Next key" value had to be pre incremented
$next_key = ++$last_key; //pre increment
echo 'Next key: ' . $next_key;

Comment: @u_mulder
array (size=13)
  'contact001' => string 'jasmine' (length=15)
  'contact002' => 
    array (size=3)
      'age' => string '33' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Ruben' (length=6)
      'tel' => string '87778787878787878' (length=17)
 when I parse in the for each loop I get  "Illegal string offset 'name'"

Answer (score 0):

```
$namejson = $firebase->get(DEFAULT_PATH . '/name/');

$data=json_decode($namejson,true);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo end($value);
}
```

Comment: $data=json_decode($namejson,true);
echo end($data);  gave me the last value i.e
[age] => 33 [name] => Robert [tel] => 87778787878787878

Comment: @ben echo end($value);

Comment: thnaks for you valuable comment , i found the solution given by @u_mulder!

Comment: $data as $key => $value , "data" - big array, "key" - pointer to scalar,  "value" - sub arryy